# login using html form

Tags: php, authentication

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="log" method="GET" action="login.php">
        username <input type="text" name="usr" style="width: 242px"></input><br>
        password <input type="password" name="psw" style="width: 242px"></input><br>
        <input type="submit" style="width: 78px" value="تسجيل الدخول">      
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my simple php file

```
<?php
    echo $_GET["usr"];
?>
```

when i pressed the submit I excepted it will print the username but it gave me this
[image]

please can someone tell me what is the problem, sorry for my bad English

Comment: You're not running a server, maybe try to install wamp so you can reach your localhost

Comment: You should run the PHP file from `localhost`. Not from `file://`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not** running the file on a php server... you are just reading the file in the browser, try loading the page from a URL like: `http://localhost/mypage.php`